# Optimal triangle (minimal area) surrounding a disk

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

Using `RegionWithin` it's quite easy to evaluate a parametric triangle with maximal area inside the disk(constant):

```
dreieck = Triangle[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}] (*parametric triangle*)
sol = NMaximize[{Area[dreieck], RegionWithin[Disk[], dreieck]},Flatten[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]] 
Graphics[{FaceForm[Lighter[Gray]], Disk[], FaceForm[Darker[Green]],dreieck /. sol}]
```

[image]

Trying to solve a similar problem *triangle with minimal area surrounding the disk* makes difficulties

```
NMinimize[{Area[dreieck], RegionWithin[dreieck, Disk[] ]}, Flatten[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}]]
```

`RegionWithin[dreieck, Disk[] ]` can be evaluated separately (huge expression) but NMinimize
starts evaluation without result( EvaluationMonitor shows no progress)

Any idea why Mathematica doesn't solve? Thanks!

Comment: `LeafCount[RegionWithin[dreieck, Disk[], GenerateConditions -> False]]` results in `377569`

Comment: @user64494 Thank you. That means I should first try to reduce the condition...

Comment: That reduction is doubtful. Here is a small part of the output `-x2^3 y1 + 3 x2^2 x3 y1 - 3 x2 x3^2 y1 + x3^3 y1 + x1 x2^2 y2 - 
  2 x1 x2 x3 y2 - x2^2 x3 y2 + x1 x3^2 y2 + 2 x2 x3^2 y2 - x3^3 y2 - 
  x2 y1 y2^2 + x3 y1 y2^2 + x1 y2^3 - x3 y2^3 - x1 x2^2 y3 + 
  x2^3 y3 + 2 x1 x2 x3 y3 - 2 x2^2 x3 y3 - x1 x3^2 y3 + x2 x3^2 y3 + 
  2 x2 y1 y2 y3 - 2 x3 y1 y2 y3 - 3 x1 y2^2 y3 + x2 y2^2 y3 + 
  2 x3 y2^2 y3 - x2 y1 y3^2 + x3 y1 y3^2 + 3 x1 y2 y3^2 - 
  2 x2 y2 y3^2 - x3 y2 y3^2 - x1 y3^3 + x2 y3^3 >= 0`.

Comment: Its `LeafCount[%]` performs `205`.

Comment: @user64494 That looks much better,thanks! How did you calculte this simplification? I tried `Reduce[RegionWithin[dreieck, Disk[]]]` but Mathematica doesn't solve it in finite time.

Comment: It looks you didn't read my previous comments, The above  polynomial inequalty of degree 4 in 6 variables is approximately 205/377569 ==0.00054 part of the complete output. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason might be that Mathematica fails to find an initial point that satisfies these complex conditions.

```
a = RegionWithin[dreieck, Disk[]];
FindInstance[a, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}, Reals]
```

Also doesn't terminate. Mathematica doesn't seem to have an option for giving initial points. The more interesting question might be, what can you do solve this problem instead.

You simplify the search for feasible points a lot by choosing different variables. Note that any minimal triangle will touch the circle at 3 points and the lines will be tangents of the circle.

Each point on the unit circle is defined via one real number $b, c, d$ for the sake of rotational symmetry we can assume `b == 0`.

$$x \cos(b) - y \sin(b) + 1 = 0$$
defines a set of $(x,y)$ which is the tangent at the point $(\sin(b),\cos(b))$.

We can calculate the intersection of two tangents by finding a point $(x,y)$ that satisfies both equations.

```
Solve[{x Cos[b] - y Sin[b] + 1 == 0,  x Cos[c] - y Sin[c] + 1 == 0}, {x, y}]
```

Has the solution

```
{x -> -((Sin[b] - Sin[d])/(Cos[c] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[d])), 
 y -> -((-Cot[b] + Cos[c] Csc[b])/(-Cos[c] + Cot[b] Sin[d]))}
```

Using those points we can now construct a triangle and calculate the area as you did above. However we also need a constraint that the center of the triangle (average of edge points) must lay in the circle. Futhermore only want to consider triangles bigger than the circle itself.

This results in this query:

```
NMinimize[{Area[
   Triangle[{{-((Sin[b] - Sin[c])/(
       Cos[c] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[c])), -((-Cot[c] + 
        Cos[b] Csc[c])/(-Cos[b] + Cot[c] Sin[b]))}, {-((
       Sin[b] - Sin[d])/(
       Cos[d] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[d])), -((-Cot[d] + 
        Cos[b] Csc[d])/(-Cos[b] + Cot[d] Sin[b]))}, {-((
       Sin[c] - Sin[d])/(
       Cos[d] Sin[c] - Cos[c] Sin[d])), -((-Cot[d] + 
        Cos[c] Csc[d])/(-Cos[c] + Cot[d] Sin[c]))}}]], ({-((
        Sin[b] - Sin[c])/(
        Cos[c] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[c])), -((-Cot[c] + 
         Cos[b] Csc[c])/(-Cos[b] + Cot[c] Sin[b]))} + {-((
        Sin[b] - Sin[d])/(
        Cos[d] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[d])), -((-Cot[d] + 
         Cos[b] Csc[d])/(-Cos[b] + Cot[d] Sin[b]))} + {-((
        Sin[c] - Sin[d])/(
        Cos[d] Sin[c] - Cos[c] Sin[d])), -((-Cot[d] + 
         Cos[c] Csc[d])/(-Cos[c] + Cot[d] Sin[c]))})/3 \[Element] 
   Disk[], Area[
    Triangle[{{-((Sin[b] - Sin[c])/(
        Cos[c] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[c])), -((-Cot[c] + 
         Cos[b] Csc[c])/(-Cos[b] + Cot[c] Sin[b]))}, {-((
        Sin[b] - Sin[d])/(
        Cos[d] Sin[b] - Cos[b] Sin[d])), -((-Cot[d] + 
         Cos[b] Csc[d])/(-Cos[b] + Cot[d] Sin[b]))}, {-((
        Sin[c] - Sin[d])/(
        Cos[d] Sin[c] - Cos[c] Sin[d])), -((-Cot[d] + 
         Cos[c] Csc[d])/(-Cos[c] + Cot[d] Sin[c]))}}]] >= 
   Area[Disk[]], b == 0}, {b, c, d}]
```

which gives us

```
{5.19615, {b -> 0, c -> 2.0944, d -> -2.0944}}
```

which when plotted using `RegionPlot`
looks like:
[image]

#### An exact solution using Herons Formula

Wikipedia gives an exact formula for [the length of the incircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Radius) based on the side length a,b,c. Herons formula gives the area of the triangle using the same information.

`s := (a + b + c)/2; Heron = Sqrt[s*(s - a) (s - b) (s - c)];`

`Minimize[{Heron, 1 == Sqrt[(s - a) (s - b) (s - c)/s], a > 0, b > 0,  c > 0}, {a, b, c}]`
Minimizes the area of a triangle with a circle of radius 1 inside.
If the resulting expression is Fully Simplified the objective turns out to be `3 Sqrt[3]` (matching our numerical calculation before) while all lengths are `2 Sqrt[2]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Trying `NMinimize`  with the option `"InitialPoints" -> { 0, 2, -2, -5/4, 2, -5/4}}` also does not lead to success

Comment: I followed through with the strategy i gave.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. My purpose is to find a more general solution using `RegionWithin` applied to a parametric Region (for example a Polygon) and a constant region  (for example a Polygon) .

Comment: I understand. I'm afraid Mathematica's generic implementation of RegionWithin results in to complicated terms for it to be solved by an generic algorithm. I would look into is solving the problem for a fixed outer shape, calculating the sensitives of the solution with regard to those parameters and then re optimize until you see no improvement. While this won't guarantee global optima, you will might get a solutions using NLP and maybe an active set approach. It is possible that more specialized algorithms exist for some shapes i'm not aware off. Maybe see Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance

Comment: Do you have some examples of what you are working in more detail, or a more complicated test problem?

Comment: Consider for example a ConvexHullRegion of a pointcloud  and try to find the enclosing quadrilateral with minimal area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comments and interest!

Comment: Ok, this might lend itself to an implementation in a programming language meant for numerical computation. In what industries/applications does this problem have an application?

Comment: For example if you try to scan a distorted image, thereby try to identify the GeometricTransformation, which reconstructs the rectangular image.

Comment: After some digging (for 2d) i would recommend this approach. You can transform https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191066/transforming-an-arbitrary-quadrilateral-to-a-unit-square https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863702/870285 an arbitrary quadrilateral into an unit square. Thus checking that all points are inside an quadrilateral is O(n) (compared to convex hull which has O(n*log(n)) operations. There are formulas to calculate the area of an quadrilateral. I hope this turns out to be feasible.

Comment: Yes,`Minimize[{Sqrt[(x + y + z)*x*y*z], x*y*z == x + y + z, x > 0, y > 0, 
  z > 0}, {x, y, z}]` also work. Here   a=x+y,b=y+z,c=z+x